# Linear Algebra: Turning matrix into its reduced echelon form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have augmented matrix:

1 1    2 | a

1 2  1 | b 

0 3 -1 |c

where a, b, and c are arbitrary constants. In the end, I got something like:

1 0    0 | -c+2b-a-(1/2)(c-3b+3a)

0 1  0 | b-a+(1/2)(c-3b+3a) 

0 0 1 | (1/2)(c-3b+3a)

Row operations I performed (in order): -R1 added to R2; -3R1 added to R2; -R3 added to R1; (1/2)R3; -R2 added to R1; R3 added to R2; -R3 added to R1

Can someone please check if my work is right? What I have looks so amazingly ugly that I just wonder if I made some simple arithmetic mistake or if one of the row operation steps is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is alright, though you can simplify a bit more the last column.

Comment: @Subhadeep: Thank you for linking me to that! I will definitely refer to that in the future. Although I hope the current problem I wrote is acceptable and readable?

Comment: @thanasissdr: Thank you! ^-^ I simplified it when I changed it into the algebraic form x = blah, but it still looked ugly. It does look less of a mess though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks good! An easy ( albeit not as easy as you would hope) way to check is to simply use your elementary row matrix rows to reconstruct your original matrix.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought about working my way backwards to check my work. I'll keep this in mind for the future!